# Unitization via "End points compactification"

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras

We know  that every compactification of  locally compact Hausdorff spaces correspond to a unitization of  $C^{*}$  algebras. For example the one  point  compactification corresponds to the minimal unitization and the  Stone Chech compactification correspond to the maximal unitization "Multiplier algebra".

In this  question I would  like  to know if  something is  already  known for  noncommutative  analogy of "End points  compactification" as described bellows?:(Your  answers  and  comments  are very appreciated)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_%28topology%29

and

[End point compactification for metric spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42961/end-point-compactification-for-metric-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [**Noncommutative End Theory**](http://www.msp.org/pjm/1998/185-1/pjm-v185-n1-p03-p.pdf) by Akemann and Eilers.